# List of all upper configs

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is there any way to retrieve all upper configs which influence on my web-application config?

Comment: Programatically?  I'm not sure - maybe using System.IO.File and System.IO.Directory.  If you have access to the server and don't need it programatically, you can simply do a visual walk up the directory tree.  Also don't forget that Machine.config can have an influence as well.

Comment: Just curious - what is the use case for this?

Comment: @Decker97, some upper-level config set some value and I want to find out which one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably only using search of files under your application directory. But it brings only .config files which is included in the project. Probably it's no way to get global `web.config` and `machine.config` because of security reasons.